# Redux Toolkit - GET is never called, OPTIONS never returns

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm converting my app to use the new React Redux Toolkit, but am running into an issue when I try to call a GET function.  The OPTIONS call is initiated but the GET never is called.  I can't think of any reason why the thunk would partially run.  The structure of the code has been working using an older Redux setup, so essentially the only thing I've changed to go from working to not working is using the Toolkit, specifically the `createAsyncThunk()`.

In my Login page component's `mapDispatchToProps`...

```
 fetchProfile: email => dispatch(fetchProfileAction({id:email})),
```

Setting up my `asyncThunk`...

```
export const fetchProfileAction = createAsyncThunk(
  'profile/fetchProfile',
  async (params, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await api.userApi.fetchProfile(params);
    return response.data;
  }
);
```

The API call...

```
fetchProfile: (params) => axios.get(authEndpointUrl(`users/${params.id}`)).then(response => response.data),
```

And the log statements.  The OPTIONS has no Headers or Cookies...
[image]

Comment: You are reading response.data.data, once in the api you return response.data and in the action you return response.data. Can you see the request in the network tab and can you see what is dispatched in the redux dev tools and can you see what changes to the state these actions cause?

Comment: Yes, I see your point about referencing response.data.data - but, it doesn't even reach that point. The GET is never called, everything stops after OPTIONS is called.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely try to fetch something from another domain while breaking CORS policy. Check your browser's console, you probably find a warning there about broken CORS policy, if so you should contact an administrator of the API and ask him to fix its headers (it is a backend issue).

Axios is calling `OPTIONS` to check what methods are available for given URL, at this point `OPTIONS` header is blocked by CORS or they return information that `GET` / `POST` is not available, so axios does not even try to call an endpoint.

Comment: Yes, even simpler than that.  The server wasn't running and all the login API calls were going to Cognito, so it appeared things were running fine until a GET occurred.  My thanks-for-having-common-sense to you.